# Cyanogen mod 7.2.0 keyboard backlight not working properly

Tags: cyanogenmod, keyboard, htc-desire-z, backlight

I have recently rooted my phone (HTC Desire Z A.K.A. Vision) and installed Cyanogen 7.2.0. I have noticed that my keyboard and softkeys backlight no longer work properly.

What used to be the case: The backlight of the softkeys lit up when turning on the screen. The backlight of the keyboard lit up when "sliding" open my phone. After dimming both sets of buttons would come back to life at use.

What is the case now: The backlight of the softkeys only turns on when I manually adjust the brightness of the screen. The same applies for the keyboard backlight but only when the phone is "open".

Does anyone know a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some time a friend of mine goofed around and actually found the fix:
CyanogenMod Settings > Display > Automatic Blacklight
In here enable 'Use custom' and then look at the values in 'Edit other levels...'. The levels you want to edit are either the ones under 'Buttons' which are the values for the backlight of the soft keys (Home, menu, back and search) and the values under 'Keyboard' is for the  keyboard backlight. A value of 30 is standard for the 'Buttons' and the values for the 'Keyboard' are only 0 or higher than 0. (Even though you can choose values between 0 and 255, it doesn't seem to matter visibly.)